# Can I databind to properties of a custom class (instantiated in xaml) that then forms the content of a templated listboxitem

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml, windows-phone-7

Any help on this really appreciated. In summary I'm trying to databind to properties of a custom class instantiated in xaml that then forms the content of a templated listboxitem (phew!).

I have a simple c# class called MenuItem. It has two properties:
- Heading
- Icon

Concentrating on just one of those menu items (i.e. to provide a simple example of where I am stuck) If I do this (with the values hard coded) it works fine:

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBoxItem ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
        <myclasses:MenuItem Heading="News" IconImage="News.png"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
</Listbox>
```

Where MenuItemTemplate is an appropriate DataTemplate in the resources section binding each property) containing lines such as:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbHeading" Text="{Binding Heading}">
```

Wheareas when I try to use binding to set the Heading property it falls over (AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE error)- e.g.:

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBoxItem ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
        <myclasses:MenuItem Heading="{Binding NewsHeading, Mode=OneWay}" Icon="News.png"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
<Listbox>
```

I've wondered if it is because I'm doing some kind of double binding (i.e. the template is binding to a value on the MenuItem class that needs to be bound) and that's not possible? I've tried having the properties declared as dependency properties but no difference (although I only learned about those today so I may be missing something).

I know I could set the menuitem objects up in the view model, and bind from there, but I would like to understand why the above doesn't work (as for my purposes there are advantages in constructing the menu items in the xaml).

Thank you!!!!
Ian

---

thanks for sticking with this. I agree the listbox might not be needed - but even if I reduce it to just one item in a contentcontrol:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
    <myclasses:MenuItem Heading="{Binding NewsHeading, Mode=OneWay}" IconImage="News.png"/>
</ContentControl>
```

I still have the same problem - which is that I can get databinding to work within the content of a contentcontrol (prior to it being presented by the datatemplate referred to in ContentTemplate) using purely xaml.

I.e. the above bit of xaml doesn't work - it throws an error on the bit that binds the NewsHeading:

```
Heading="{Binding NewsHeading, Mode=OneWay}
```

So I am trying to understand whether what I'm doing is impossible, or whether it is but I'm doing it wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have multiple MenuItem classes (because you're putting them in a listbox and ti wouldn't make sense to do that if you just had one). You need to bind the collection to the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox`.

Somehting like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyMenuItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Heading}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Note that the above assumes you've set the DataContext on the page to an object with a property called `MyMenuItems` which is a collection of your `MenuItem` objects.

To see a full example of this, look at the default code created when you create a new "Windows Phone Databound Application".

**Edit:**
Based on your comments, it seems that a `ListBox` is not the most appropriate solution to your needs. A ListBox is designed/intended to take a collection of items and display them in a list.

If you have a number of different objects which you know about at design time and simply wish to have them one on top of another (giving the appearance of a list) you could simply put them inside a ScrollViewer and/or a StackPanel (or other appropriate container). Plus, you would still be able to databind if you did it this way.

Comment: Hi Matt - thanks for answering - however it's not what I'm looking for. In my case I want to be able to have different types of items in my listbox (so I can't just bind to a standard collection). I know one way of doing this (using a WP7 equivalent of a DataTemplateSelector to dynamically apply a template based on item type) but I hoped to be able to do it declaratively in the Xaml (as that provides a better design preview). So I need a way of having a listbox that can show e.g. a menuitem, then a different kind of item, then another menuitem.

Comment: @Ian how could you specify this at design time if you don't know what the items are until runtime? If you know what they could be then the `DataTemplateSelector` is the way to go. Be aware that having different items in a list can have an impact on performance when the list gets long.

Comment: I've got it working using a custom DataTemplateSelector (not natively available in WP7), but the problem is (in wp7 anyway) it requires that all the items be set up in code. I would much prefer the items of the listbox to be set up in Xaml. That way (e.g. a designer) could specify which items are to appear on a menu page, with which images, and in what order - without having to worry about the code in the viewmodel. Some of the items, however, require databound text (e.g. translations of a menu heading, or a status messsage) so I still wanted databinding to be available. Hope that explains it.

Comment: Hi Matt - thanks for your edit regarding the listbox not being appropriate - I have reduced my answer to just using a contentcontrol (see other answer in this thread) to illustrate the problem I still have.